# Extract data from xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to extract data from a XML file for my project based on C#.
The XML file is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Chemicals>
    <Titrates>
        <Titrate Name="Hydrochloric Acid" Basisity="1" Molarity="10" Normality="10" >
            <Experiments>
                <Experiment Name="AcidBase"></Experiment>
                <Experiment Name="Redox"></Experiment>
          </Experiments>
        </Titrate>
        <Titrate Name="Sulphuric Acid" Basisity="2" Molarity="20" Normality="50" >
            <Experiments>
                <Experiment Name="AcidBase"></Experiment>
            </Experiments>
        </Titrate>
        <Titrate Name="Nitric Acid" Basisity="3" Molarity="50" Normality="40" >
            <Experiments>
               <Experiment Name="AcidBase"></Experiment>
            </Experiments>
        </Titrate>
    </Titrates>
    <Titrants>
        <Titrant Name="Sodium Hydroxide" Acidity="1" Molarity="10" Normality="20" >
            <Experiments>
               <Experiment Name="AcidBase"></Experiment>
            </Experiments>
        </Titrant>
        <Titrant Name="Calcium Hydroxide" Acidity="1" Molarity="20" Normality="40" >
            <Experiments>
               <Experiment Name="AcidBase"></Experiment>
            </Experiments>
        </Titrant>

    </Titrants>
    <Indicators>
        <Indicator Name="Phenolphethalin" Color="Pink" >
            <Experiments>
                <Experiment Name="AcidBase"></Experiment>
            </Experiments>
        </Indicator>
        <Indicator Name="Methyl Orange" Color="Orange" >
            <Experiments>
               <Experiment Name="AcidBase"></Experiment>
            </Experiments>
        </Indicator>
    </Indicators>
</Chemicals>
```

As you can see, The chemicals are divided under titrants, titrates and indicators and then each chemical may be used in multiple experiments.
The file is just a sample so, please ignore the chemistry aspect :P.
So, for a particular experiment I need to extract the relevant data of all the chemicals that will be used in it.

Example:

For AcidBase Titration I would need the Name, Molarity, Basisity etc ( under titrates ) of the particular titrate. Same way for titrants and indicators whichever have AcidBase in their Experiment part.

Comment: What is your question? What have you got already?

Comment: Do you have an XSD that describes the data in the file? If not you should probably look into using [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) or deserializing to objects you define yourself.

Comment: Do you know LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize the XML to an objectModel using an [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then you can access the information easily in your code.